# POST of json over Flask API wont accept my argument

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios

I have a problem with POSTing a JSON to my API...

API:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return jsonify({"about":"Hello wwworld"})

@app.route('/json-example', methods=['POST']) #GET requests will be blocked
def json_example():

    req_data = request.get_json()

    return jsonify(req_data)
```

AXIOS in Vue:

```
  <script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!',
        result:'',
        test:   {
                "language" : "Python",
                "framework" : "Flask",
                "website" : "Scotch",
                "version_info" : {
                    "python" : 3.4,
                    "flask" : 0.12
                },
                "examples" : ["query", "form", "json"],
                "boolean_test" : true
            }
      },
      methods:{

        getResults () {
            axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/`)
            .then(response => {this.result = response.data})
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error)
            })
        },

        getResults2 () {
            axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/json-example`, {
              params: {
                test
              }
            })
            .then(response => {this.result = response.data})
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error)
            })
        }

      }
    })
  </script>
```

For some reason i cant access **test** json that i would like to pass as an argument. First function getResults () works just fine but when I try getResults ()2 it gives me following error:

> index.html:45 Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined

Can somone please give me a hint how to fix it? I tried posting the json via Postman ans got a proper reponse.

Thank you
Jakub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to do this in  `getResults2`

```
    getResults2 () {
        axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/json-example`, this.test)
        .then(response => {this.result = response.data})
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }
```

Comment: My pleasure. Glad I could help :)